# How do I capitalize all text in a column of data in an Access Query while keeping the name of the field the same?

Tags: ms-access, capitalize, strconv

How do I capitalize all text in a column of data in an Access Query while keeping the name of the field the same?

I tried entering "SPEC: StrConv([SPEC],3), but I get an error that I have a circular argument (which, isn't too surprising). So how do I get around this?

Is there a totally different approach to capitalizing in queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Given:  we have a field named [SPEC].
- Problem:  need query to grab [SPEC] and convert it to all caps, but
  with the same field name
- Added:  We will call the table that holds the field [SPEC],
  [tblTable]

Solution:
What we need to put in the query builder is the following:

```
SPEC: UCase([tblTable].[SPEC])
```

That way the machine can figure out that Query.SPEC isn't the same identifier as tblTable.SPEC

Equivalently:

```
SELECT UCase([tblNames].[FirstName]) AS FirstName
FROM tblNames;
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Ucase function

```
Ucase(String)
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with your vision....check the "accepted" answer and also my answer....the only issue with my answer is that the poster lacks any knowledge and needs a step by step guide to use an Access function....